solana token transfer An account required by the instruction is missing
I minted an NFT with anchor and would like to send it to a different address.
NFT Mint address is BoWAiiGuVTEY7Jsck6KuCoRPMDUgC5wpH84RoRBBNMDS
program
use anchor_spl::token::{mint_to, Mint, MintTo, Token, TokenAccount,TransferChecked,transfer_checked};

pub fn transfer_test(ctx: Context<TransferTest>) -> Result<()> {
        
        let cpi_accounts = TransferChecked {
            from: ctx.accounts.from.to_account_info(),
            to: ctx.accounts.to_ata.to_account_info(),
            authority: ctx.accounts.authority.to_account_info(),
            mint:ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info()
        };
        let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();
        // Create the CpiContext we need for the request
        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);

        transfer_checked(cpi_ctx,1,0)?;
        Ok(())
    }

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct TransferTest<'info> {
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = authority,
        associated_token::mint = mint,
        associated_token::authority = authority,
    )]
    pub to_ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    /// CHECK: This is the token account that we want to mint tokens to
    #[account(mut)]
    pub from: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    /// CHECK: the authority of the mint account
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}

test
const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
  anchor.setProvider(provider);
  const program = anchor.workspace.Test as Program<Test>;
  const authority = provider.wallet.publicKey
  const mintAddress = new PublicKey("BoWAiiGuVTEY7Jsck6KuCoRPMDUgC5wpH84RoRBBNMDS");
  it("Burns tokens from the token account", async () => {
    // Call the burn_token function from the program
    const mint = mintAddress;

    // Assuming the token account is already created and tokens are minted
    const tokenAccount = anchor.utils.token.associatedAddress({
      mint: mint,
      owner: authority,
    });
    const to = anchor.utils.token.associatedAddress({
        mint: mint,
        owner: new PublicKey("H8tmHjLuphAnMqgGdJLWryXp9kySduF53wWcPcvsmkeB"),
      });
    const params = {
        mint:mintAddress,
        toAta:to,
        from: tokenAccount,
        authority: authority,
        tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
        associatedTokenProgram: ASSOCIATED_PROGRAM_ID,
        rent: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
      }
      console.log(params);
    await program.methods.transferTest()
      .accounts(params)
      .rpc({skipPreflight:true});
  });

Even after checking

https://docs.rs/anchor-spl/latest/anchor_spl/token/

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
The same error occurs even change transfer_checked to transfer.
Referring to the answer to a similar question, I tried changing associated_token::mint and associated_token::authority to token::mint and token::authority, but a Missing signature for public key error occurred.
token

https://solscan.io/token/BoWAiiGuVTEY7Jsck6KuCoRPMDUgC5wpH84RoRBBNMDS?cluster=devnet

transaction

https://solscan.io/tx/3exA7f26WviFWK7Jh78jn2H7VZdZ6TZ5yAqVmik2GGfewVfD7U1MosBH8s2G7KMEpccHxog6TWXLhXVUnz9EV5CH?cluster=devnet

